# How to add a requirement.txt in my project python

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, requirements.txt

In fact When I do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to put all the packages that I use in my project in a requirements.txt, it puts all python packages that I have in my pc and this despite I have activated my visual environment.

In my project path I activated my venv then I did `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
I had a requirement.txt with packages that had nothing to do with my project. I installed all my packages with pip. What did i did wrong.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: Recommended reading: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- So in your case, I would rather call something like this `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have inherited some global site packages when you created the venv. Likely ones you had pip installed while not in any venv. Try creating the venv using

Windows:
`python -m venv (venv name here) --no-site-packages`

Linux:
`python3 -m venv (venv name here) --no-site-packages`

The no site packages argument tells python to ignore all global-site packages when creating the new venv.

Comment: C:\Users\name\Desktop\project\backend>python3 -m venv venv --no-site-packages
usage: `venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear] [--upgrade] [--without-pip] [--prompt PROMPT] [--upgrade-deps] ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]
venv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages`   It's seems that not work any suggest?

Comment: sorry my bad. try `virtualenv --no-site-packages venv`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's start out with the idea that you have a mixed globals + local packages venv.  And you want to only freeze what's in the virtualenv.

###### You want to see what's in what

```
pip freeze  > local.global.txt

deactivate

pip freeze > global.txt
```

OK, so now you have 2 lists.

#### Let's make a **BIG ASSUMPTION**!

*All the packages your project **REALLY** need are in the local venv site_packages.*

This is probably wrong, but bear with me.

###### So let's look at what's in what by using a file differ.

```
diff global.txt local.global.txt
```

I am going to filter this a bit.  `>` means it's local+global, `<` means it's global only.

```
> Django==3.2.14
> django-celery-results==2.4.0
> django-debug-toolbar==3.5.0
> django-redis-cache==3.0.1
> django-waffle==2.5.0
> django-webpack-loader==1.6.0
```

All this django stuff?  It's only in my virtualenv.  I **want** it in requirements.txt for this project.

Now, let's look at what I don't see in this diff but is in **BOTH** global.txt and global.local.txt

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==7.1.2
jupyter-console==6.4.0
jupyter-core==4.9.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
```

Yes, I can see jupyter from within my virtualenv.  But I did not install it there, I am only seeing the global version.  You don't want it.

###### Put anything in the `requirements.txt` that comes with `>`

```
# yes the 2 > are not a typo.
diff global.txt local.global.txt | grep '>' > requirements.txt
```

Then you need to clean up the leading `>`

Sorry, these are some unix utilities being used here.  Windows will have similar utilities in powershell or wsl (I think).

If worse comes to worse you will have to build your requirements.txt manually, by only keeping lines that DONT exist in `global.txt`

#### About that big assumption:

This is where you create a new venv with only this requirements.txt and you try to run your application and/or its tests.

Anything that it uses that you did not install locally in the virtualenv will cause errors.

Figuring out stuff that you had in the virtualenv because you installed it there by mistake (my jupyter packages for example, if I had put it there) is harder to identify.

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze` is not a good option if you have chunk of installed packages, because `pip freeze` will include all unused packages and packages from different venv that has nothing to do with your current project in the `requirements.txt`.

You should use `$ pipreqs --encoding=utf8 <project-dir>` which is supposed to generate `requirements.txt` based on used packages in the current project.
[Read pipreqs doc](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)
You first run the below `pip` command in terminal to install `pipreqs` incase you don't have it installed.

```py
pip install pipreqs
```

After the installation run the following in terminal to generate your `requirements.txt`:

```py
$ pipreqs --encoding=utf8 [<path>]
```

or

```py
pipreqs --encoding=utf8 [<path>]
```

**Note:** Make sure you replace `\` with `\\` for your path in case you encounter `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`.

**Example:**

```py
pipreqs --encoding=utf8 projects\working_directory
```

output:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'projectsworking_directory\\requirements.txt'
```

**Solved**

```py
pipreqs --encoding=utf8 projects\\working_directory
```

output:

```
INFO: Successfully saved requirements file in projects\working_directory
```